# Example of a function on non-compact metric space

Tags: analysis

I am looking for a sequence of functions with following property.

a. Continuous function on non-compact metric space that is monotone and point-wise convergent but not uniform convergent. Is it possible.

It should be obvious, I came up with this question while playing with Dini's Theorem.

Comment: For a bounded example: On $[0,1)$, let $f_n$ be the function whose graph consists of the straight line segments connecting the points $(0,0)$, $(1-1/n,0)$, and $(1,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x},\quad x>0.$$ For the sequence, take $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}n &: 0<x\leq\frac{1}{n}\\ \frac{1}{x} &: \frac{1}{n}<x\end{cases}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be $[0,\infty)$, and define $f_n:X \to \Bbb R$ by 
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}0 & x\le n \\ x-n & n \le x \le n+1 \\ 1 & x\ge n+1 \end{cases}$$
Then each $f_n$ is continuous, and for any $x\in X$, $f_n(x)$ is decreasing and converges to $0$, but the convergence is not uniform.